# Cloud Asset API not enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-asset-inventory

Our project has enabled Cloud Asset Inventory API, I can view it from UI, but I get this permission error. I am the owner of the project.

```
➜ gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    ---

You are now logged in as [myemail].

➜ gcloud asset export  --content-type resource --project xxx --output-path "gs://export-resources-t/resources_updated.yaml" --format=yaml
Export in progress for root asset [projects/xxx].
Use [gcloud asset operations describe projects/xxx/operations/ExportAssets/RESOURCE/530109afbb66bdaf2be325e11897c83c] to check the status of the operation.


➜ gcloud beta resource-config bulk-export --resource-format=terraform --path output --project xxx
Exporting resource configurations to [output]...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.resource-config.bulk-export) Permission denied during export. Please ensure the Cloud Asset Inventory API is enabled.
```

Comment: I do have the IAM permissions to run the command. I am the owner of the project.

Comment: Probably this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467083/gcp-auth-permission-denied-when-executing-cloud-asset-export#comment128019721_72467083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171179807) case When the destination is in the same project, the user doesn't need to grant additional permission/role to the built-in service account, it is only needed when the destination is in a different project.

If this is not your issue then try using this method. i.e.,

For this service account you should add the role 'roles/cloudasset.serviceAgent' (which has all the required permissions).

Run this: `gcloud beta services identity create --service=cloudasset.googleapis.com --project=<project number>`

The above command will create the needed identity, then copy the name of the service account identity created and use it with the following command to grant the required role:

```
gcloud beta projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_name> --member='serviceAccount:[Service_Account]' --role='roles/cloudasset.serviceAgent
```

Please replace the [Service_Account] with the actual service account identity created in the first command.

After performing the above steps, you will be able to run the`gcloud beta resource-config bulk-export --project=<project_name> --resource-format=terraform` command.

For more information follow this [doc](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234833177).

Comment: # set $PROJECT_ID, $PROJECT_NUMBER

`$ gcloud beta services identity create --service=cloudasset.googleapis.com --project $PROJECT_ID && gcloud beta projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member="serviceAccount:service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com"  --role='roles/cloudasset.serviceAgent' && gcloud alpha resource-config bulk-export --path=./ --resource-format=terraform  --project $PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 2):

How I was able to solve this problem.
Firstly I have also enabled the cloud asset API via using the cloud console as well as using cloud SDK command below.

```
gcloud services enable cloudasset.googleapis.com
```

But still it was throwing me errors like this

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.resource-config.bulk-export) Permission denied during export. Please ensure the Cloud Asset Inventory API is enabled.
```

So to resolve this I give my user account the following permissions:

- Cloud Asset Owner (this one was the bad guy)
- Storage Admin
- Service Usage Admin

And just used the SDK command as usual and it started working.

I was taking full import of my project so for that I used this command.

```
gcloud beta resource-config bulk-export   --path=entire-tf-output   --project=$PROJECT_ID   --resource-format=terraform
```